# Mountebank: Ability to add names for stubs

Tags: stubs, mountebank

Is there a way to tag **stubs** of an **imposter** with some identifiers so that while debugging, we can easily get the matches for a specific stub?

Currently the stub has a `matches` field, but when we want to verify programmatically if a certain stub has really been called, there is no way to get the matches for a specific stub we are interested in.

If there was a way to tag a stub, then we can filter the stub based on the tag and get the matches for that specific stub.

Answer (score 2):

You can add whatever information you want to the stub and see it reflected when you request the imposter details.  For example:

```
{
  "protocol": "http",
  "port": 3000,
  "stubs": [{
    "name": "example",
    "responses": [...]
  }]
}
```

Then you'll see that "name" field when you send a GET request to http://localhost:2525/imposters/3000.

-Brandon

Comment: I was not aware of it. I will try it and update here. Thanks.